# jqueryUI droppable "drop" function firing on "over" only if i have on my draggable a "connectToSortable" option set

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

You can see the code on http://designvictim.com/jqueryui/index.html

I'm trying to make something similar to the widget drag and drop from
Wordpress.

I've gotten pretty close to what we wanted to accomplish but we wanted
to be able to when you drag a item out of the "Drop Area's" and drop
it outside then it would erase itself and send of course an Ajax call
with the updated contents. That is why i made the #body droppable.
Also if you start a drag from the Module Column to one of the drop
areas i wanted it to be sortable directly before dropping it and i was
able to accomplish this with "connectToSortable: '.moduleContainer' "
but now every time i start with an item from the module container and
start dragging and hover one of the drop areas and continue to another
one, the drop function of the $('#body').droppable() fires which
boggles my mind!

I hope its some clumsy coding of mine and not a bug of jqueryUI.
Thanks in advance for any help and i hope i made myself clear on the
problem.

Answer (score 2):

Figure it out!

I made my .moduleContainer **droppable** and **sortable** and you shouldn't do that. Automatically when you make a group sortable it becomes droppable. I couldn't find this information anywhere in the jQuery UI documentation though.